# How can I use set() with my ArrayList without error?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I created my Variables class, and made my ArrayList.
I need this ArrayList <Variables>, but it gives error with the set method, how can I set my r in position 1? that was initialized to 0.

The error: no suitable methos found for set(int,int) method AbstractList.set(int, Variables) is not applicable

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity {
Variables variables = new Variables();
ArrayList<Variables> variablesArrayList = new ArrayList<Variables>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    variables.setR(0);
    variables.setCont(0);
    variablesArrayList.add(variables);

}}
```

My code:

```
public class T1 extends ActionBarActivity {

Variables variables = new Variables();
ArrayList<Variables> variablesArrayList = new ArrayList<Variables>();
int r;
Random random = new Random();

String[] teste = {
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3",
        "test4",
        "test5",
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_t1);

    r = variables.getR();
    r = random.nextInt(4);
    variablesArrayList.set(4, r);

    String jogarPergunta = teste[r];


}}
```

My Class Variables

```
public class Variables {

// default constructor
public Variables() {
}


private int cont = 0;

private int r = 0;

public int getCont(){
    return cont;
}
public void setCont(int cont){
    this.cont = cont;
}

public int getR(){
    return r;
}
public void setR(int r){
    this.r = r;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ArrayList is defined to contain `Variables` objects:

```
ArrayList<Variables> variablesArrayList = new ArrayList<Variables>();
```

but you are trying to put an integer when using the set method:

```
variablesArrayList.set(4, r);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not working because you are trying to set r in array list. First try to get desired variable object from particular position using `variablesArrayList.get(index)` and then set r on it.

try this:

```
variablesArrayList.get(0).setR(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add an integer....

```
variablesArrayList.set(4, r);
```

change something like this...

```
variablesArrayList.get(your number).setR(r);
```

`variablesArrayList.get(your number)`
 will return your varibales and using that object you can call any methods defined in the varibales...